# Ruby on Rails console --help not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails 5 installed via rvm, and when I type rails -h or rails generate model -h etc, I only get the standard help message :

```
 $ rails generate model -h
Usage:
 rails new APP_PATH [options] ...
```

I should be able to get help with all of the different rails commands on the console.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you on the project directory?

Comment: Ok. thanks, I was one level above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!  I was in the wrong directory and/or I hadn't generated a new project yet.
It's working fine now, thanks.